# Immutable Data with Readonly in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In my quest to learning TypeScript, I am currently reading about Immutable Data with Readonly in TS. I know what the code below is supposed to do, which is return 0 and "1".   I am confused tho as to what exactly `type ReadonlyInterface<T>` and `function genericInterfaceToReadOnly<T>` are suppose to be doing.  Can somebody please explain?

```
interface OriginalInterface {
    x: number;
    y: string;
}

type ReadonlyInterface<T> = { readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P] };

function genericInterfaceToReadOnly<T>(o: T): ReadonlyInterface<T> {
    return Object.freeze(o);
}

const original: OriginalInterface = { x: 0, y: "1" };
const originalReadonly = genericInterfaceToReadOnly(original);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ReadonlyInterface` type uses the [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) syntax to create a generic which turns all of the properties in the type parameter into read-only parameters. Note that this is equivalent to the [built in `ReadOnly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#readonlytype) type. So, in this case, `ReadonlyInterface<OriginalInterface>` would be:

```js
interface OriginalInterface {
    readonly x: number;
    readonly y: string;
}
```

Marking the properties as readonly in the type level. The `genericInterfaceToReadOnly` takes an object of type `T`, and returns a readonly version of it by using [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze), which makes the object immutable at runtime as well. Essentially, the type combined with the function allow you to make a value immutable in both the type and runtime levels.